# Does ClassUtils have a method returns primitive class from a wrapper class?

Tags: spring

Does [`ClassUtils`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html) have any method returns a corresponding primitive class from a primitive wrapper class?

I found [`resolvePrimitiveIfNecessary`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html#resolvePrimitiveIfNecessary-java.lang.Class-) but I can't find the opposite.

```java
Class<?> c = ...;
if (ClassUtils.isPrimitiveWrapper(c)) {
    Class<?> primitive = @@?
}
```

I know I can always get the `TYPE` field value from any primitive wrapper class. And I want to know is there a method for that with [`ClassUtils`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html).